# Implement Best-Practice Error Message in Spring REST Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am writing a server-side REST application for a mobile app. I have been trying to setup an exception handler which follows the explanation [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/spring-mvc-rest-exception-handling-best-practices-part-2), where instead of showing some HTTP error page, the client receives a JSON object similar to this one:

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "code": 40483,
    "message": "Oops! It looks like that file does not exist.",
    "developerMessage": "File resource for path /uploads/foobar.txt does not exist.  Please wait 10 minutes until the upload batch completes before checking again.",
    "moreInfo": "http://www.mycompany.com/errors/40483"
}
```

I have modeled my exception on those detailed in the guide, and they seem to be working well (the custom errors are being shown in the console).  But I got stuck at [this](https://stormpath.com/blog/spring-mvc-rest-exception-handling-best-practices-part-2#restexceptionhandler-spring-configuration) point, because I don't know where I'm supposed to put the bean configuration.

Given that I have all my exception handlers, resolvers, etc., I thought I'd try go around it differently. At this point I would still get Spring's Whitelabel error page when I entered an invalid HTTP request, but this time with my custom error messages from my exceptions. So I figured if I tried to implement my own `ErrorHandler` as explained [here](http://www.baeldung.com/custom-error-page-spring-mvc), I might be able to construct the JSON objects using Gson or something, instead of the way the previous article went about it.

I tried to get a bare minimum `ErrorHandler` working:

```java
package com.myapp.controllers;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
public class ErrorMessageController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath(){
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
    public String renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request){

        String errorPage = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");

        return errorPage;
    }

}
```

So I expected to get something like a solitary `404` appearing on the webpage. But instead I'm getting a Tomcat error page:

[image: Tomcat Error Page]

Why is this? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code")` should be an `Integer` and you're casting it as a `String`. This causes an error during the error handling, which pops up the default Tomcat error handler.

If you cast it as an `int`, it will work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
public int renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request){

    int errorPage = (int) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");

    return errorPage;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you just want to return certain JSON structure, you could use `@ExceptionHandler` methods in stead of implementing an `ErrorController`.

For example, let's say you have the following controller:

```
@GetMapping
public String getFoo() throws FileNotFoundException {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File resource for path /uploads/foobar.txt does not exist");
}
```

If you want to handle all `FileNotFoundExceptions` in a particular way, you could write a method with the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(FileNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public ErrorResponse notFound(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), 40483, "Oops! It looks like that file does not exist.", ex.getMessage(), "http://www.mycompany.com/errors/40483");
}
```

In this case, `ErrorResponse` is a POJO containing the fields you want. If you want to re-use this for all your controllers, you can put this in a `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: So where do I put the `@ExceptionHandler` method? In a new RestController?

Comment: You can choose it. If it only applies to a single controller, then you can put that method in the same controller class. If it applies to all controllers, then you create a new simple class and just annotate it with `@ControllerAdvice`   and nothing else.